# SQL to remove rest of string if a character exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to remove the end of a string in my query if a character exists in the name.

Example:
name = `Jeff(2)`

The `(n)` is irrelevant to me but I'm lacking in SQL knowledge apparently and  can't find something similar.

Comment: you should be more specific..do you only want to extract substrings up to the first `(` character if it exists? please show some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: Sure, sorry. So the field is stored as "Jeff (id)" but I only need to extract Jeff.  Some fields are just stored as "name" though and do not have the id. So my expected output needs to be "Name" regardless if it has the "(id)" at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function **SUBSTRING_INDEX**

```
UPDATE yourTable
set `name` = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`name`, '(', 1)
WHERE name LIKE '%(%)';
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT  SUBSTRING_INDEX('Jeff(2)', '(', 1);
+------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX('Jeff(2)', '(', 1) |
+------------------------------------+
| Jeff                               |
+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]>
```